# In R: replacing specific factor in a dataframe with another existing factor

Tags: r

I have a large data frame with a variable 'home_ownership' which can take the factors : `'own', 'mortgage', 'none', 'other'`

I want to replace the values which are `'none'` to `'other'`.

I tried

```
df$home_ownership[df$home_owneship == "none"] <- "other"
```

which runs without an error.

But then when I do `table(df$home_ownership)` I still get a count of 46 for "none" Whilst I was expecting it (and wanting) it to have a count of 0.

Comment: Since you don't provide any data, its hard to help. Add `df$home_ownership <- factor([df$home_ownership)` after the assignment to reset the factor levels. BUT note that you have a misspelling in the code you pasted. `df$home_owneship`

Comment: Please include a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's a typo in

```
df$home_ownership[df$home_owneship == "none"] <- "other"
```

with the missing r it should do what you want ;)

--

But if you're really talking about the levels of a factor this should help:

```
levels(df$home_ownership)[levels(df$home_ownership)=="none"] <- "other"
```

or use factor() again after replacing the value.
For renaming levels look [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Renaming_levels_of_a_factor/).